# Migrating a service from one docker container to another with zero downtime

Tags: proxy, migration, docker, containers

I am trying to experiment with container service migration. I have three machines where two of them have the exact service running which does some work and returns some HTML data. The third machine is my client which I am using for sending requests to the service running in one of the containers mentioned before. All three machines for simplicity are in the same network. Since I know the IP's of all the machines, I use my client's browser to send a request to one machine and get the HTML data on my browser.

What I am interested in doing is that if I send the request to the same machine but I turn off the wifi for the first server machine, I want the request to be diverted to the second server machine automatically and get the response from there.

Now could you tell me some ways to do this ? Would I need an additional router/registry which runs another container which keep tracks of the IP's of the server machines and acts as a proxy and receives the request and forwards it to one the server machines. As soon as the first server is disconnected, the router should probably have a timeout period if it doesn't receive any response and in that case forward the same request to the other server. Once it gets the response back it would forward it to the client.

Any more thoughts or flaws in this approach?

Thanks !

Comment: do research on fleet with docker, you should have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your situation, it looks to me that you require `HAProxy` and something like [synapse](https://github.com/airbnb/synapse) that will monitor your resources and serves from the available pool of resources.
You just need to ensure you are using different ports for different services and include them in your configuration file. Please refer to the [Configuration](https://github.com/airbnb/synapse#configuration) section to try it out.
I have seen people using this to update production servers with zero downtime.

Comment: Thanks Sabin. I'll give Synapse a read and see if it solves my case. Does synapse run as a independent container which talks to other containers ?

Comment: see also this post about HAproxy and docker http://blog.tutum.co/2015/05/05/load-balancing-the-missing-piece-of-the-container-world/